# How do I create a custom date-picker Html Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How do I build a custom html helper like `Html.TextBoxFor()`

I would like to create a date-picker helper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found these on a search. They appear to be very promising, and are in a clean tutorial-style format.

- [Creating A DatePicker Extension In ASP.Net MVC](http://www.codesprouts.com/post/Creating-A-DatePicker-Extension-In-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)
- [JQueryUI Datepicker in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62031/JQueryUI-Datepicker-in-ASP-NET-MVC.aspx)

**Edit:** I downloaded the sample project from the first tutorial, and added the following to the HtmlHelperExtensions class to get strongly-typed `...For()` behavior. The principle is simple: forward strongly typed data binding to the existing plain methods. Note that this has the *Works on My Machine* seal of approval, and should be carefully reviewed and, if necessary, adapted to your scenario.

```
public static string DatePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    string imageUrl)
{
    if (expression == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
    }

    var expressionText = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    return DatePicker(htmlHelper, expressionText, imageUrl, htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(expressionText));
}
```

Comment: Nice tutorial on how to build a custom DatePicker Helper. My only concern is that there is nothing in theses tutorial about Model extension like Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyDate)

Comment: @Jean - I added a little something that might help bridge the gap between the tutorials and the `DatePickerFor` behavior you want. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: Thanks kbrimington, it's exactly what I was looking for.